# R - Replace row variables within a data frame with variables from another row

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have a list of data frames similar to the reprex below but with 100+ columns:

```
# reproducible example
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5"),
  Date = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02"),
  Value1 = c(rnorm(5, 2, 3), rnorm(5, 4, 1)),
  Value2 = c(rnorm(5, 12, 4), rnorm(5, 5, 8)),
  Value3 = c(rnorm(5, 22, 13), rnorm(5, 7, 10))
)

# transform data frame into list
df <- split(df, df$Name)
```

For each data frame in the list, I would like to replace the last row with values from the one prior row.  For example, for each data frame in the list, I would like to replace `[2, 3:5]` with `[1, 3:5]`.

```
> tail(df[["Name1"]], n = 2)
   Name       Date    Value1    Value2    Value3
1 Name1 2018-01-01 0.9184539 15.658510 29.219707
2 Name1 2018-01-02 3.8875463  3.628546  9.777399
```

I'm not sure if transforming my data frame into a list is the best way to go about this so any other suggestions are welcome.  I tried tackling this as outlined below but my attempt only replaces the last row in the data frame with the second to last row.

**My Attempt**

```
# reproducible example
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5"),
  Date = c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02"),
  Value1 = c(rnorm(5, 2, 3), rnorm(5, 4, 1)),
  Value2 = c(rnorm(5, 12, 4), rnorm(5, 5, 8)),
  Value3 = c(rnorm(5, 22, 13), rnorm(5, 7, 10))
)

# arrange by Name and Date
df <- df %>% dplyr::arrange(Name, Date)

# attempt to replace 
df[length(df$Name), c(3:5)] <- df[length(df$Name)-1, c(3:5)]

# result
tail(df, n = 4)

> tail(df, n = 4)
    Name       Date    Value1    Value2    Value3
7  Name4 2018-01-01  3.242383 -11.44217 -1.215688
8  Name4 2018-01-02 -4.042093  18.18184  1.544271
9  Name5 2018-01-01 -1.930195  13.18662 18.889372
10 Name5 2018-01-02 -1.930195  13.18662 18.889372
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution. I don't think converting to a list is necessary. `df` is the data frame in your example. We can replace the last row with `NA` and then use `fill` to fill with the previous row.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), 
            funs(ifelse(row_number() == max(row_number()), NA, .))) %>%
  fill(starts_with("Value")) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#    Name  Date       Value1 Value2 Value3
#    <fct> <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 Name1 2018-01-01  1.35   14.5   34.2 
#  2 Name1 2018-01-02  1.35   14.5   34.2 
#  3 Name2 2018-01-02  2.42    4.43  19.5 
#  4 Name2 2018-01-01  2.42    4.43  19.5 
#  5 Name3 2018-01-01  4.60   14.1   15.8 
#  6 Name3 2018-01-02  4.60   14.1   15.8 
#  7 Name4 2018-01-02  6.36   11.4    9.40
#  8 Name4 2018-01-01  6.36   11.4    9.40
#  9 Name5 2018-01-01  0.214   8.34  33.8 
# 10 Name5 2018-01-02  0.214   8.34  33.8
```

The following could be even better. This one does not use the `fill` function, and it does not change the row order as well.

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Value")), 
            funs(ifelse(row_number() == max(row_number()), 
                        nth(., n = max(row_number()) - 1),
                        .))) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 10 x 5
#    Name  Date       Value1 Value2 Value3
#    <fct> <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 Name1 2018-01-01   4.40  13.5   28.0 
#  2 Name2 2018-01-02   1.82   8.23  20.9 
#  3 Name3 2018-01-01   1.07  16.9    7.50
#  4 Name4 2018-01-02   1.09   8.05  14.4 
#  5 Name5 2018-01-01   1.17  11.6   24.0 
#  6 Name1 2018-01-02   4.40  13.5   28.0 
#  7 Name2 2018-01-01   1.82   8.23  20.9 
#  8 Name3 2018-01-02   1.07  16.9    7.50
#  9 Name4 2018-01-01   1.09   8.05  14.4 
# 10 Name5 2018-01-02   1.17  11.6   24.0
```

Comment: very nice solutions.  Both work well with the reprex data and in my actual data frame when I define one column name in the `starts_with()` function.  However, defining more than one column name like so `starts_with(c("Value", "OtherValue", "OtherOtherValue"))` produces the following error:  `Error in starts_with(c("Value", "OtherValue", "OtherOtherValue")) : is_string(match) is not TRUE`.

Comment: @On_an_island Try `vars(starts_with("Value"), starts_with("OtherValue"), starts_with("OtherOtherValue"))`

Comment: Found that exact suggestion not too long after I posted my response to you.  Thank you, your second solution works great and is MUCH faster than using `fill`!